# Maven2 Dependencies and Native Libraries

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a Java project which I've used Maven2 and the assembly plugin to help with compiling and packaging, there's quite a few dependencies so its quite a nightmare to manage especially since I'm quite new to Maven.

Anyway, I'm using a Java library which has an accompanying native Windows library (DLL) and im trying to work out how to specify the native library as a dependency or something so that it exists on the path and my application can use the library at runtime.

Comment: Is it too late to switch to ant?

Comment: 'switching to ant' doesn't solve the problem.  It replaces a dependency management system with the lack of a same.

Comment: To be fair, with Ant you can use Ivy to manage dependencies, but you still haven't solved the native library problem.