# Maven integration with native libraries

Tags: maven, integration, native, libraries

I am using Android with Maven in my project . It depends on zbar.jar which in turn depends on the secondary artifacts like .so files. I am able to install the zbar.jar in the maven repository , but my secondary artifacts like .so files are not getting pulling through the Maven repository.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using [android-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) ?

Comment: yes Iam using android-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Maven is designed to handle Java code. The .so files are binaries compiled for a specific architecture.
Are you fully aware on the implications of using .so files?

You can

1. Either package the so file in a jar file and write custom code to
   copy them in their correct position before your application runs
2. or locate a maven plugin that does what you want. (or even an
   Android-Maven specific plugin)

See also [Maven2 Dependencies and Native Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220386/maven2-dependencies-and-native-libraries)