# How to create multiplatform executable jar with native libraries for sikulix api using maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, sikuli, native-code, multiplatform

I have problem creating executable single jar dependent on sikulixapi.

Relevant parts from pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am using maven-assembly-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>                                          
                <mainClass>com.myProject.myClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>                    
    </executions>                                                
</plugin>
```

I am able to produce working **jar** on windows. **jar** contains sikulixlibs directory in **jar** root and everything works OK on windows platform.

But I would like to produce **jar** working multiplatform. **jar** created on windows contains only windows subdirectory in sikulixlibs and due to this fact there are missing native binary code when calling in linux.

```
[error] RunTimeINIT:  *** terminating: libs to export not found on above classpath: /sikulixlibs/linux/libs64
```

How to include all linux/windows/OSX native libraries into produced **jar**?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220386/maven2-dependencies-and-native-libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited dependecies part od pom.xml, add additional maven artifacts, one for every supported OS, and make maven producing jar including all native libraries.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixlibslux</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixlibsmac</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixlibswin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```