# Seam + hibernate + jsf on weblogic

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, weblogic

I'm making a little project with Seam, Hibernate and JSF. This project run on JBoss 5.1.

My boss wants to deploy this project on WebLogic. I read on the seam documentation that seam and WebLogic don't work fine together.

I would like to know if I can use Hibernate (with JPA) and JSF on WebLogic and what framework (struts, spring?) I can use to replace Seam.

Edit: I read in the seam documentation ([chapter 39, weblogic integration](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/reference/en-US/html_single/#weblogic)) and I find that:

For several releases of Weblogic there has been an issue with how Weblogic generates stubs and compiles EJB's that use variable arguments in their methods. This is confirmed in the Weblogic 9.X and 10.0.MP1 versions. Unfortunately the 10.3 version only partially addresses the issue as detailed below. So, I want to know if other problems like this exist.

Edit 2: I use Weblogic 10.3

Comment: What version of WebLogic are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by *"don't work fine together"*? I've already seen Seam applications on WebLogic and the Seam documentation provides detailed instruction to run [Seam on WebLogic](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/weblogic.html) without mentioning any blocking issue.

If you have something specific in mind, please clarify. But in the current state of the question, my advice would be to stick to Seam and to deploy your application on WLS.

Comment: It's maybe because WebLogic has (had) a bad rep. But you can say the same of for example WebSphere :)

Comment: @BalusC Are you serious? Most feedback I got about WebLogic (at least for production) is positive and I have personally a very good opinion of it. But let's not start discussing this :)

Comment: This is just what I observed as far at various forums the last decade. Not a personal opinion since I don't have practical experience with it. But you know, humans complains more often loudly than they compliments. Like as with Maven. You already got my vote btw, that link to Seam documentation is very confirming.

Comment: @BalusC: I was just curious because my *perception* is different. But I agree (and funnily, I wrote something similar about Maven in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861382/why-does-maven-have-such-a-bad-rep/2035150#2035150)).

Comment: Yes, I know that, I've read this answer before (my vote is also still there). I personally find Maven sound great, but I don't really know where to start in existing projects.

Comment: @Pascal I read this chapter and I find that:

For several releases of Weblogic there has been an issue with how Weblogic generates stubs and compiles EJB's that use variable arguments in their methods. This is confirmed in the Weblogic 9.X and 10.0.MP1 versions. Unfortunately the 10.3 version only partially addresses the issue as detailed below. 

So, I want to know if other problems like this exist.

Comment: @BalusC I see :) Regarding Maven, getting started on an existing project is indeed one of the difficult part and Maven's documentation is not its biggest strength. Just in case, my advice would to start with the [Maven by Example](http://www.sonatype.com/products/maven/documentation/book-defguide) book (and the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin), to get used to it on a pet project. And once familiar with the layout, the IDE integration, the main "goals", to Mavenize an existing project (pretty easy actually if your project is not too exotic).

Comment: @Kiva You should add this to your question and also mention the WebLogic version you're using (and if you have any link, please add it). I'll be glad to provide some feedback.

Comment: True, I'll have to create some free time and motivation first to play around :)