# What object-oriented concepts has maven?

Tags: oop, maven

The article [Maven, not just another build tool](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven,+not+just+another+build+tool) claims that *Maven brings the object oriented approach to the build tools table. I'm completely failing to see how. Actually, I see neither any [OO concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_features_and_concepts) there, nor anything I'd call an object.

I'm not starting another [rant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861382/why-does-maven-have-such-a-bad-rep) here, I'm just asking how this claim can be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Maven modules can inherit from other maven modules, though what they inherit tends to be instructions for building and configurations of metadata, *not* the files that they apply those instructions to. Typically, the parent modules are done of type `pom` (i.e., without standard outcome artefacts), and container modules are also done that way. Indeed, containers are often also parents, even though I suspect that's not that great a way to do things (though the containment relation is *not* inherited).

Things that you *would* inherit would be like the version of a dependency to use, or a configuration for a plugin, or the location of the repositories from where to get dependencies or to which result artefacts will be pushed. Indeed, all Maven modules automatically inherit from a built-in POM that supplies much of this information. You can find out what the overall effect of all this inheritance is for a particular module by getting its ***effective POM***:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

(If you've got Maven integrated into your IDE, you'll have to look around for how to find this information. For example, with Eclipse, the effective POM is on a separate tab in the Maven POM editor view.)

Answer (score 0):

> [**What is the POM?**](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM)
>
> POM stands for "**Project Object Model**". It is an XML representation of a Maven project held in a file named pom.xml.
>
> One powerful aspect of Maven is in its handling of project relationships; that includes dependencies (and transitive dependencies), inheritance, and aggregation (multi-module projects).

Maven has many OO concepts including:

- aggregation - multi-module projects
- inheritance - parent projects

In Maven project is an object, module is an object and projects can depends on others projects.