# While using spring framework, getting error - import org not found

Tags: java, spring

I started learning spring framework recently. I added all the spring libraries to the classpath of my project. But I am getting a import org not found error.

```
package com.springlearnging.springdemo;

//Getting error at this import
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class HelloSpringApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //load spring config file
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        //retrieve bean from spring container

        //call methods

        //close context

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your dependencies?

Comment: Do you have `spring-context` jar in your classpath?

Comment: I have added all the jars that are there in spring release 5.0.8. from this url. http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/

Comment: Using  maven with spring will help you extremely to build correctly and  fastly your  project ,some maven features  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234046/10275943)

Answer (score 0):

If you are leaning the Spring Framework, it will be much easier for you to start with [Spring Boot](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) and the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).  The Spring Initializr allows you to generate a correctly configured initial project.

Consider also using the [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools) which is customised Eclipse made for Spring development.

Comment: I understand that spring boot gives a opinionated project structure. I just want to understand why the above is not working. In the udemy tutorial I am following they were able to do this.

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, you should mention it explicitly in your question and provide a link to it.

Comment: It's a udemy course. It's a paid link. That's why I didn't mention. I just wanted to understand if adding the all the spring jars to classpath is enough or not

Comment: Ok, I understand. Can you edit your question and explain how do you build and run the application and add the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with java version. Compiling with JavaSE-1.8 solved the issue